# Using addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL to prevent backing up files

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, icloud

I can't get this to work. My app was rejected for allowing files to be backed up that were unnecessary. To stop this I was told to use addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL to mark the files not to be backed up.

I placed the following code, provided by Apple, in my AppDelegate.

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);

    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                                  forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
    if(!success){
        NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"\n\nFile %@ removed from backup.\n\n", URL);
    }
    return success;
}
```

I then add the following in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
[self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"blue" ofType:@"jpg"]]];
[self addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fred" ofType:@"jpg"]]];
```

It works fine in the simulator. On the actual phone though, it does't work and gives me what I think resolves to a permissions error.

```
Error excluding blue.jpg from backup Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 513.)" UserInfo=0x1740741c0 {NSURL=file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C8559ABA-181E-4686-A5ED-2ADCA283D2E4/PetJournal.app/blue.jpg, NSFilePath=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C8559ABA-181E-4686-A5ED-2ADCA283D2E4/PetJournal.app/blue.jpg, NSUnderlyingError=0x174058e10 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted"}
```

Can anyone help guide me through this.

Comment: you have to include this function where you are saving your image

Comment: The image isn't being saved it's in my bundle. It comes with the app.

Comment: show me how you are calling your appdelegate

Comment: Sorry. I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: When the user first launches the app, a SQLite DB is created and put in the documents directory. I think this is what is getting flagged. I have asked for more clarification, as the DB holds all the user data, and I am sure they would want it backed up. Everything else in the app is just included with the app bundle when I submit it.